# Different ways of detecting smile

Tags: opencv, face-detection, feature-detection, openimaj

I would like to know more about different ways of detecting smile on image. As far as I know, there are many libraries that are allowing to detect face and smile. The ones that I've tried are:

- [FaceSDK](https://www.luxand.com/facesdk) from Luxand
- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)
- [OpenIMAJ](http://openimaj.org/)

Instead of just using them, I'm curious about how they are working. I know that OpenCV and OpenIMAJ are working based on Haar classifiers. I don't really follow, how FaceSDK is doing face and smile detection though.

I can imagine, that you can get two different ways of smile detection:

1. Perform fully emotional detection. You can find eyes, nose, mouth and other features on face and then compute emotion based on those informations. If you get "happy" emotion, you can assume, that there is smile (or something like that, just finding mouth and checking curve on lower lip?).
2. Similiar to Haar cascades, search image and try to find object that is similiar to the one that you are searching (having many negative and positive samples). This one seems to be faster, but less trustworthy if not used with some "helpers".

Is there any other way? Do you guys have some articles on one of those ways?

Comment: Your question is way too broad and is effectively a request for an off-site resource. You should download OpenCV and go through the source code and / or read the documentation to see how they work.

Comment: I wanted to focus on different ways of smile detection, didn't really know that this is too broad - sorry. Although I don't know, where I should ask this question.

Comment: You can ask specific questions about specific issues here just fine. Your question (as it is now), however, asks a broad question about how smile detection works. Any answer to that would be like a thesis on its own. I'm pretty sure there are books on the topic that you can get and tutorials in the various libraries - you should look at those.